# Update Column if Null from previous values

Tags: sql, loops, null, db2, sql-update

I am using DB2 SQL. I have a table name ITEMATRIX which looks like -

```
ITNBR   LBRCST  MFGOH   STDUC   YRMNT
RM-013         0    0   499.6   2010-02
H-178          0    0   164.5   2010-02
FP9-003        0    0   6       2010-02
FP9-059        0    0   2       2010-02
A94-103B-M     0    0   0       2010-02
140-07-1012C   0    0   10      2010-05
140-07-1012C   0    0   0       2010-06
```

then

```
 ITNBR  LBRCST  MFGOH   STDUC   YRMNT
 140-07-1012C   0   0   10      2010-05
 140-07-1012C   0   0   **10**      2010-06
```

etc etc......

I want to update the `STDUC` field if the value is 0 or Null to value present to the nearest month. Lets say for `ItNBR` `140-07-1012C`the `STDUC` is `0` for `2010-05`, then first I have to find if that Item Number has a standard cost in the year 2010 for any month, if yes then copy the value of the last month which is `2010-04` to it. There are many records with the same Item number which I am transposing later. Can anyone give me some ideas of how to go about this?

Thanks 
Varun

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding correctly, but you could do something like `isNull(STDUC,0) = 0` which would return all `0` or `NULL` values

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply
I want to change those Null and 0 values of STDUC to an actual value if present for other month. if it 100 for the previous month and this month's value is null, I would like the previous value in the place of NULL.
I think I l edit my question with a example
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shifted the process to EXCEL and could do it easily using `IF` and `VLOOKUP` on single cost values starting from the earliest month and then simply comparing the values of previous month and changing accordingly and then create `UPDATE` statements using `&`.I shifted the process to EXCEL and could do it easily using `IF` and `VLOOKUP` and then create `UPDATE` statements using `&`.

Answer (score 0):

I think he following is the logic that you want:

```
update itematrix
    set stduc = (select stduc
                 from itematrix im2
                 where im2.stduc <> 0 and im2.stduc is not null and im2.itnbr = itematrix.itnbr
                 order by yrmnt desc
                 fetch first 1 row only
                )
    where stduc is null or stduc = 0
```

I haven't tested this in DB2.  There may be a problem using `fetch first` on the same table as the one used in the update.  I find the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_fetchfirstclause.htm) ambiguous.

If you don't need an actual update, but just want to see the value, then try:

```
select itemmatrix.*,
       (select stduc
        from itematrix im2
        where im2.stduc <> 0 and im2.stduc is not null and im2.itnbr = itematrix.itnbr
        order by yrmnt desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       )
from itemmatrix
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how should I even check if the ITNBR has a NOT NULL value for that particular year in the same update statement

Comment: @user1554963 . . . This puts in the previous value.  If you want a value from the same year, then you need something like `left(im2.yrmnt) = left(itematrix.yrmnt`.

Comment: Thanks for the logic,I tried the above logic, can someone tell me why `fetch first 1 row only` is giving an error on unknown token

Comment: I tried this but giving the same error as above
`select  yrmnt
, ITNBR
, case
  when STDUC is not null then STDUC
  else
  (
  select  STDUC
  from    ADCLIBT.ITEMAT yt2
  where   yt1.ITNBR = yt2.ITNBR
  and yt2.STDUC is not null
  and yt2.yrmnt < yt1.yrmnt
  and not exists
  (
  select  *
             from    ADCLIBT.ITEMAT yt3
                where   yt1.ITNBR = yt2.ITNBR
                        and yt2.STDUC is not null
                        and yt3.yrmnt < yt2.yrmnt and yt2.yrmnt < yt1.yrmnt
      fetch first 1 row only
                )
        ) end as STDUC
from    ADCLIBT.ITEMAT yt1`

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff,
Yes, I want to update those values actually. Do I have to use a cursor if the fetch does not work? Is there any other way to do this and include the `left(im2.yrmnt) = left(itematrix.yrmnt` clause as well?

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `select` version and create a new/temporary table.  Then do the update from there.

Comment: The fetch command does not support version 5 I guess, hence it is not working, is there any other way to do the same

Comment: You're still going to need an `ORDER BY` to make that `FETCH FIRST` work properly...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . You are very correct.  Thank you.  I added it to the "select" version, since it should work there.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : Thanks, can you please explain to me in detail if I want to update in the same table. Would I have to use 2 different loops within the cursor. I have to fit this portion into another existing procedure

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Thanks, can you please explain to me in detail if I want to update in the same table witjout creating a new one. Would I have to use 2 different loops within the cursor one for `YRMNT` and `ITNBR`? I have to fit this portion into another existing procedure in DB2 iSeries V5R4.

Answer (score 0):

You ca use LAG() function if using DB2 9.7: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/dbtrue/entry/lag_lead_first_value_last_value_totally_new_in_db21?lang=en

Comment: thanks for commenting but we are not using this version of DB2
Thanks again!